# sed: find function call and insert before its closure

Tags: macos, sed

Using sed (on macOS), how can I find a pattern, find the next closing curly bracket `}` after the pattern and then insert a new line of text above this bracket?

To explain, I have a file looking like this…

```
...

init() {
  this.init_featureA();
  this.init_featureB();
}

...
```

I'd like to set up a command that finds the `init()` function call and adds a new function call at the bottom of it, i.e. before it's closing curly bracket. The output should be as follows...

```
...

init() {
  this.init_featureA();
  this.init_featureB();
  this.init_featureC();
}

...
```

This is my current implementation, which inserts the new function call at the start of the `init()` function:

```bash
sed -i '' -e '/init() {/ {
a\\
this.init_featureC();
}' PATH-TO-FILE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `sed` command with range search:

```bash
sed '/init() {/,/}/ {
/}/ i\
  this.init_featureC();
}
' file
```

**Output:**

```bash
...

init() {
  this.init_featureA();
  this.init_featureB();
  this.init_featureC();
}

...
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^init() {/{:a;/\S/h;//!H;n;/^}$/!ba;x;s/\S.*/whatever/mp;x}' file
```

This inserts `whatever` before the first occurrence of `}` after `init() {`, preserving white space.